# Passing custom parameters to FancyBox

Tags: php, jquery, fancybox

I'm developing a hotel booking and reservation management system.

I have a series of venues, which the user selects via a radio button. Once they select the map button, I want to send the venue name, longitude and latitude data to a Fancy Box window, so Google Maps can begin the process of determining route data, which makes specific use of [a route planning tutorial](http://www.dreamdealer.nl/tutorials/getting_directions_with_google_maps.html).

I've tried...

```
function fancyboxLocation(href, venue, lo, la) {
   $.fancybox({
       'hideOnContentClick': true,
       'height': 430,
       'padding': 0,
       'width': 700, 
       'type': 'iframe',
       'href' : href,
       'venue': venue,
       'lo': lo,
       'la': la
   });
}

<a href="javascript:;" onclick="fancyboxLocation('<?php echo config_item('base_url'); ?>venues/locations/route', '<?php echo $venues['name']; ?>', '<?php echo $venues['longitude']; ?>', '<?php echo $venues['latitude']; ?>')" title="Plan Route">
```

Although the window appears, my personal parameters (venue, lo and la) are being stripped out.

The parameters are finding their way into the fancyboxLocation function, but they're not travelling any further.

Any ideas how I do this?

Comment: I have no idea what FancyBox might or might not do with them, which is why I'm here. I had hoped it would pass them, since I had no reason to assume it wouldn't.

Comment: I've had to abandon FancyBox and use something different, as not being able to pass parameters is a total killer.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could call ajax content

```
$.fancybox({
    'hideOnContentClick': true,
    'height': 430,
    'padding': 0,
    'width': 700, 
    'type': 'iframe',
    'href' : href,
    'ajax' : {
        type    : "POST",
        data    : 'venue='+escape(venue)+'&lo='+escape(lo)+'&la='+escape(la)
    }
});
```

Comment: I'd prefer not to send them as parameters of the URL. Is there no way to send them directly as variables, or do I need to explore some other method of producing a pop-up window?

Answer (score 1):

// On document ready

```
const fancyFunction = (elementEvent) => {
    const cta = elementEvent.data('cta');
    elementEvent.fancybox({
        autoSize: false,
        autoPlay: true,
        width: 510,
        autoHeight: true,
        beforeLoad: () => {
            console.log('beforeLoad', cta);
        }
    });
};

$('.fancy-domec').each((i, e) => {
    fancyFunction($(e));
});
```

// On HTML

```
    <div class="ctas">
        <p><a href="#fancy-domec" class="fancy-domec" data-cta="add">Add something</a></p>
        <p><a href="#fancy-domec" class="fancy-domec" data-cta="check">Check something</a></p>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but I figured it might help someone else. Hope you got everything working properly.

The FancyBox API has an open method that looks like this:

```
$.fancybox( [jQuery object] );
```

So you can create a simple javascript function similar to the following that just uses the above method. For example:

```
function displayFancybox(param1, param2) {
     // Open FancyBox
     $.fancybox(document.getElementById("myFancyBoxContainer"));

     // Do whatever you want with your parameters (maybe write them to a div)
     document.getElementById("someDiv").innerHTML = param1;

     // Or maybe initialize a google map
     initialize(param1, param2);
}
```

Here's the html link the user will click to trigger FancyBox:

```
<a onclick="displayFancybox('some text', 'some more text');" href="#" title="Some Title">Click Me!</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
//another solution is after data-selector="blabla" in html

//use this in script:

    $('[data-fancybox="gallery"]').fancybox({

        /*callback cad call my own function after play */
        afterShow: function( instance, current ) {
        alert( 'Clicked element:' );
        /*to get data-selector value
       note selector is already ok in fancybox*/
        console.log( current.opts.selector );
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In **Funcybox 3** its working.

Html:

```
<a class="btn btn-xs btn-info" href="/test" data-fancybox data-type="iframe" data-preload="false" data-width="1200">
    Click me
</a>
```

Js:

```
Fancybox.bind("[data-fancybox]", {
        on: {
            "init": (fancybox) => {
                fancybox.items[0].src = fancybox.items[0].src + '?contentOnly';
            },
        },
    });
```

**Events Refference:**
https://fancyapps.com/docs/ui/fancybox/events